# Working with SQL datetime default current_timestamp and formatting

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a column in a MySQL database, it's a DATETIME data type and its default is CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. I'm trying to use PHP's `date_format()` function to format it bit is giving me the following error

> Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface,
>   string given in C:\wamp64\www\cms\CMS_TEMPLATE\includes\content.php on
>   line 26

```
$stmt = $connect->link->query("SELECT post_date FROM posts");
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $date = $row["post_date"];
    echo date_format($date,'d/F/Y g:i A');
}
```

Should I be using a different function or is this just a syntax error?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a function which should not be used on it's own. It is best to leave the procedural style functions behind, as they often lead to confusion and mistakes as is the case in your example.

What you need to do is create a `DateTime` object and call `format` method on it. It can be done in a single line using precedence parentheses.

```
$stmt = $connect->link->query("SELECT post_date FROM posts");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo (new DateTime($row["post_date"]))->format('d/F/Y g:i A');
}
```

As a side note, `foreach` loop usually looks cleaner than `while` loop.

```
$stmt = $connect->link->query("SELECT post_date FROM posts");
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    echo (new DateTime($row["post_date"]))->format('d/F/Y g:i A');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning states that you should be using [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) with `date_format()` ("*DateTime implements DateTimeInterface*")

Change

```
$date = $row["post_date"];
```

to

```
$date = new DateTime($row["post_date"]);
```